# Calculations with conditions in R

Tags: r, if-statement, row

I have the following dataframe:

```
   A   B   C   
1  SS  2   20   
2  TT  3   15   
3  SS  10  150
4  TT  12  121
5  UU  1   2
6  SS  4   48
7  TT  5   40
8  UU  3   12
9  UU  10  60
```

When column A is SS and if B is 2.99 and below, between 3 and 5.99, 6 and above, multiply values in column B by 10, 12 and 15 to give 20, 150 and 48 in column C for rows 1, 3 and 6 respectively.

When column A is TT and if B is 3.99 and below, between 4 and 6.99, 7 and above, multiply values in column B by 5, 8 and 11 to give 15, 121 and 40 in column C for rows 2, 4 and 7 respectively.

When column A is UU and if B is 1.99 and below, between 2 and 7.99, 8 and above,  multiply values in column B by 2, 4 and 6 to give 2, 12 and 60 in column C for rows 5, 8 and 9 respectively.

I am thinking of breaking down my computation into 2 steps by first creating a column C satisfying the conditions set followed by another column E for the computation (not shown below). I tried the following:

df %>% mutate(D = ifelse(A == 'SS' & B < 3, 10, ifelse(A == 'SS' & B > 6, 15, 12))) and got the output only for SS.

A  B  C   D 
1 SS 2  20  10 
2 TT 3  15  12 
3 SS 10 150 15 
4 TT 12 121 12 
5 UU 1  2   12 
6 SS 4  48  12 
7 TT 5  40  12 
8 UU 3  12  12 
9 UU 10 60  12

> Am trying to figure out how to repeat the above for conditions for TT and UU.

I would much appreciate any guidance how I can do this in R.

Many thanks in advance for any suggestions provided.

Comment: check `ifelse` and or `dplyr::case_when()`

Comment: Please demonstrate what you have tried that did not work

Comment: I am sorry but I just started using R about 2 months ago and could not come up with any codes. I did some research and have tried lapply, using the transform function by adding some conditions, using the if-statement but could not come up with any viable solutions. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
For (I in 1:nrow (your_df)){
        If (your_df[I,1] == "A" and your_df[I,2] > 2.99){
             your_df[I,3] = your_df[I,2] *20
}else if (new_cobdition){
......code
}else {
.......code
}
}
```

Sorry about any mistake. Just did it from my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this sutes your question but maybe this is what you looking for?

```
multipFactor <- function(a,b){
  if(a == "SS"){
    if(b < 3){
      return(10)
    else if(3 <= b && b <=6){
      return(12)
    }else if(6 < b){
      return(15)
    }
  }else if(a == "TT"){
    if(b < 4){
      return(5)
    else if(4 <= b && b <=7){
      return(8)
    }else if(7 < b){
      return(11)
    }
  }else if(a == "UU"){
    if(b < 2){
      return(2)
    else if(2 <= b && b <=8){
      return(4)
    }else if(8 < b){
      return(6)
    }
  }else{
    error()
  }
}

 C <- apply(yourDataFrame[,c('A','B')],1,function(x) multipFactor (x[1],x[2])*x[2] )
```